# Q how to generate a multi-row report by using apex 4.2.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am doing a kind of transcript application that will report different terms of the results
I have used the form before and it only display one row of the result by a PK
if I create a view like this

```
+------+--------+-------+------+
|ID    | Term   | Sub   |Grade |
+------+--------+-------+------+
|1001  |201301  |  BIO  | A    |
|1001  |201301  |  CHEM | B    |
|1001  |201309  |  HIS  | C    |
|1001  |201401  |  ENG  | F    |
+------+--------+-------+------+
```

which type of page in apex can help me to generate a multi-row report?like that:

```
ID:1001
term:201301 
SUB:  Grade:
BIO   A
CHEM  B

term:201309
sub : Grade:
his   C

term:201401
sub  Grade:
eng  F
```

if user insert new row for new term and grade ,the report should add the new term partition.

Comment: You can get something like what you want by changing the Report Template - e.g. try "vertical report" - and you can customise the template if you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create interactive report and select control break in action menu to ID of table you will get same type of report as you show above.